# Crystal report not run in visual studio ultimate 2010

Tags: crystal-reports

I have installed visual studio ultimate 2010 in computer but crystal report not show. message show that crystal.mht not installed. I have installed correct version but problem not solved.

Comment: have a look in the windows logs to see if there are more details. Also have you tried running VS2010 in Admin mode?

Answer (score 0):

Try links from article [Install crystal reports in visual studio 2010 to solve problem of getting CrystalReport.mht file](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/01/install-crystal-reports-in-visual.html)